# PCA calculation without solving eigen problem

Tags: pca

I am doing exercise.
For below question, I wonder why I don't know why I can get the answer without solving eigen problem?

[image]

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/hw/5/hw5_sol.pdf

Comment: Plot the points on Cartesian axes, then look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first principal component describes the direction of maximal variation. The three points lie along a straight line. The direction of maximal variation is along that straight line.

Consequently, the first principal component is the unit vector at either $45$ degrees or $225$ degrees from the x-axis (along the line).

It will help to draw this out, but I shouldn’t get to have all of the fun ;)

This is kind of a degenerate problem, though, since the covariance matrix of the three points will be singular.